# Sharing View between actions using knockout and ajax app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application that many views can be opened simultaneously in a tabcontrol.

I´m using knockout in all my views.

I have two actions like below:

```
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        ViewData["Mode"] = "Edit";
        return PartialView("AddOrEdit", new ParametroModel() { Codigo = "banco", Descricao = "String de conexao do banco de dados" });
    }

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        ViewData["Mode"] = "Add";
        return PartialView("AddOrEdit", new ParametroModel() { Codigo = "banco", Descricao = "String de conexao do banco de dados" });
    }
```

Both are sharing the same partial view "AddOrEdit", follow my view:

```
@model CCL.Apoio.Web.Models.ParametroModel
@{
    var isEdit = ViewData["Mode"] == "Edit";
    var isAdd = ViewData["Mode"] == "Add";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formParametro" }))
{
    @Html.Partial("_FormValidation")
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dados do parâmetro</legend>
        <dl>
            <dt>
                <label>Código</label></dt>
            @if (isAdd)
            {
                <dd>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Codigo)</dd>
            }
            else
            {
                <dd>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Codigo)</dd>
            }
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>
                <label>Descrição</label></dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Descricao)</dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>
                <label>Valor</label></dt>
            <dd>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Valor)
            </dd>
        </dl>

        <dl>
            <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
            <dd>
                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" onclick="" /></dd>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (isEdit)
    {
        <text>
        var parametroEditModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
        parametroEditModel.Save = function () {
            ModuloHelper.ajaxPut('/Api/Parametros', parametroEditModel); //Post data
        };
        ko.applyBindings(parametroEditModel, document.getElementById("formParametro"));
        </text>
    }
    else if (isAdd)
    {
        <text>
        var parametroAddModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
        parametroAddModel.Save = function () {
            ModuloHelper.ajaxPost('/Api/Parametros', parametroAddModel);
        };
        ko.applyBindings(parametroAddModel, document.getElementById("formParametro"));
        </text>

    }
</script>
```

In my view I have two observable viewmodels, one for 'add' mode and another one for 'edit' mode. I can´t use the same viewmodel for both modes cause will have two objects with the same name.....in the client side when both actions are opened. Am I doing wrong this way?

I would like to know if the is a better approach to accomplish that. Does any body can suggest another better way to do what I want?

tks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem exactly but from what I gather, that same partial view might exist twice on the same page in a tab control: one for adding, one for editing. You only want them to be able to enter the Codigo value, however, on an add. Should the edit be using an existing ParametroModel?

First, I'd suggest that you make your form id unique (perhaps by simply appending a random post-fix).  That way when you are applying your binding to the form, you can always be sure you are doing that to the right one.  Second, it looks like there is no difference in your JavaScript between an add and an edit other than the variable name. You might as well condense that into one.  The last thing I noticed is that there are no knockout data-bind attributes on your form elements. Have you gotten this working yet? Other than that, it should work fine as long as nowhere else in your views you do a blanket `ko.applyBindings(someViewModel)` after this script has executed.